# Do Osteichthyes fishes have any cartilage?

Tags: taxonomy, ichthyology, bone-biology, cartilage

Higher vertebrates, such as mammals, birds, [reptiles](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4613228/) and [amphibians](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3555487/) have both bone and cartilage.

But do [Osteichthyes fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osteichthyes) (Bony fish) have any cartilage? Or do they only have bones?

I've searched the web but I could not find anything helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Osteichthyes do have cartilage. For example, [Ancient origin of lubricated joints in bony vertebrates](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4951194/) shows images of cartilaginous tissue in the joints of several bony fish.  More generally, cartilage is required for normal bone development, and Osteichthyes are no exception (e.g. [Distinct patterns of notochord mineralization in zebrafish coincide with the localization of Osteocalcin isoform 1 during early vertebral centra formation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3517302/)).